# Android mipmap unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, size, android-drawable, android-mipmap

I have an old project to work with, a lot of refactoring and so on. All the icons and images are storing in `mipmap` folders. But there is a strange behaviour

For example, if you have an icon, which has only one size you just put it into `mipmap-nodpi` or in `drawable-nodpi` as i used, but as i mentioned before, all image resources are lying in `mipmap` folders. So wha's the issue:

When i'm putting some image into `mipmap-nodpi` it's not working for my **Samsung J4**, image, for some reason is very small, so i've also puted it into `mipmap-xhdpi`(which helped me) and accidentaly also puted it into `mipmap-xxhdpi`. So, my client showed me a sceen, that shows that on his **Samsung Galaxy S5** this image is very small also, after just blindly deleting and adding this image into different `mipmap` folders, i've found out, that this behaviour is caused by image in `mipmap-xxhdpi` folder, and when i've deleted it, image is showed correclty on **S5**

My question: So basically i'm confused. What is the logic behind **you should put image into `mipmap-xhdpi` in order for it to correclty show on Samsung J4, but you shouldn't put image into `mipmap-xxhdpi`(which is the corret folder for Samsung S5) for it to show correctly on Samsung 5? Does it have something to do with `mipmap` in particular?**

Answer (score 0):

> What is the logic behind you should put image into mipmap-xhdpi in
> order for it to correclty show on Samsung J4, but you shouldn't put
> image into mipmap-xxhdpi(which is the corret folder for Samsung S5)
> for it to show correctly on Samsung 5? Does it have something to do
> with mipmap in particular?

I don't know the logic behind it, **but you can have look on [official site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) that says drawable other than launcher icon should put in `drawable` folder not in `mipmap` folder**

---

### Under Drawable  folder

> drawable/  Bitmap files (.png, .9.png, .jpg, .gif) or XML files that
> are compiled into the following drawable resource subtypes:
>
> - Bitmap files
> - Nine-Patches (re-sizable bitmaps)
> - State lists
> - Shapes
> - Animation drawables
> - Other drawables

---

### Under mimmap  folder

> Drawable files for different launcher icon densities.

Comment: You're correct, but the things is, i want to know what causes this behaviour, i can't do this operation without client agreeing, so maybe the resources will be always in mipmap folders =(